# useSelector with React.memo vs connect

Tags: redux, react-redux, react-hooks

referring from the link.
https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks#performance

what i understand the benefit of `useSelector` hook, is to avoid **wrapper hell**. **Wrapper hell** is happening due to the usage of `connect` **HOC**. If we have to use `React.memo` **HOC** with `useSelector` due to perfomance reason, would it be better approach to simply use `connect` **HOC** instead? Because in any case we would have to be in **hell of wrappers**. If the **hell** is not by `connect` then would be by `React.memo`.

Any one please explain the benefit of `React.memo` over `connect`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Well, first, interesting enough although React.memo is a HOC it does not create the same nesting as connect does. I have created a test code:

```js
    import React from "react";
    import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
    import {connect, Provider} from 'react-redux'
    import { createStore } from 'redux'
    import "./styles.css";
    
    const MemoComponent = React.memo(function MyMemo() {
      return <div>Memo</div>;
    });
    
    const ConnectedComponent = connect(null,null)(function MyConnected() {
      return <div>ReduxConnectComponent</div>;
    })
    
    const store = createStore(()=>{},{})
    
    
    function App() {
      return (
        <Provider store={store}>
          <MemoComponent />
          <ConnectedComponent/>
        </Provider>
      );
    }
    
    const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
    ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

And here is the structure rendered:

[image]

We can see that a content for connect is rendered deeper.

Second, the docs say:

> by default useSelector() will do a reference equality comparison of the selected value when running the selector function after an action is dispatched, and will only cause the component to re-render if the selected value changed. However, unlike connect(), useSelector() does not prevent the component from re-rendering due to its parent re-rendering, even if the component's props did not change.

that means the component which useSelector will not be re-rendered when unrelated parts of the store change. And this is the most important part of the optimization. Whether optimizing with React.memo or not is now completely depends on your decision and in most cases, it simply is not needed. We use React.memo only in cases when the component is very expensive to render.

To summarize, connect wrapper was required to connect to the store. With useSelector we do not have to wrap anymore. We still need to wrap with React.memo in rare cases when we need to optimize some heavy components. The work of React.memo was also done by connect but in most cases, it was premature optimization.

Comment: You mean that the problem with useSelector, to not prevent re-rendering if parent component going rerendered, will not be resolved by memo hoc. Please confirm if I understand you correctly.

Comment: No. I think React.memo will solve the problem with such a re-render. I just say that this problem is very rare is a real problem. Only in cases, the component is slow to render or when it renders very often.

Comment: i noticed that react community are not encouraging to use redux any more. may be I am wrong.

Comment: plus now react is not discouraging to use side effects in react components, after introducing hooks and suspense.

Comment: @SheikhAbdulWahid I have noticed this myself. But this is probably because it was overused and now there are simpler ways to do things in React. However, for a very complex app with complex server interactions, I would still opt for Redux as it uniquely helps observe and control what happens in the application + there is saga which is a very useful tool in those setups.

Comment: "that means the component which useSelector will not be re-rendered when unrelated parts of the store change." but in the case of non primitives, it will rerender.

Answer (score 5):

I have been trying to get an answer for quite some time but the answers I got weren't clear. Although the theory in the Redux documentation isn't complicated: `useSelector` uses strict equality `===` and connect uses shallow equality to determine. So in both cases, if you are "pulling" a primitive value from your Redux state (number, string, boolean) you will be having the same outcome. If values haven't changed none of the components will rerender. If you are "pulling" non-primitives (arrays or objects) and the values haven't changed for both cases (useSelector, connect), then the component that uses `useSelector` will still rerender as of course `[] === []` will always be false, as they are referencing different arrays, where as the `connect`ed component will NOT rerender. Now in order to make `useSelector` behave similarly and not rerender, you can do this:
`const object = useSelector(state => state.object, shallowEqual)` You can import `shallowEqual` from `react-redux`. Or alternatively use a memoized version of that piece of state by using the `reselect` library:

```
const makeGetObject = () => createSelector(state => state.object, object => object)
```

and add it to your selector such as: `const object = useSelector(state => state.object, makeGetObject);` I have created this codesandbox when I was trying to get at the bottom of it (check the comments at the `WithUseSelector` component): [useSelector vs connect()](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-euler-i7xt7?file=/src/components/WithUseSelector.js)

Comment: No, this answer is quite wrong. useSelector also won't cause component to rerender in case of "pulling" non-primitives that haven't changed, because store will return the same referenced value.

Comment: No, your example demonstrates totally different thing. I already proved it myself before commenting your response. So please don't be bothered. The reason why WithUseSelector component is being rerendered is because the parent component (App) is rerendering. On the other hand connect HOC has its performance optimization. We have to add React.useMemo when using useSelector if we want to have the same benefit which HOC provides. You can check on the documentation (https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#performance)

Comment: useSelector's selector Fn without useCallback will be called whenever the component is re-rendering, because functional component will create new function every render. And useSelector also will be called whenever any redux store's value changes, because selector Fn already had subscribed to the redux store. But it won't trigger component rerendering unless its return value hasn't changed.

Comment: "useSelector uses strict equality ===" is right, but useSelector itself does not trigger rerender in case of "pulling" reference type value that haven't changed, because again, store will return the same referenced value. The reference will be the same unless you are not using a method that triggers copy of the object such as .map, .filter, .slice or whatever. You can reference CAUTION section here. https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-5-ui-react#reading-state-from-the-store-with-useselector

Answer (score 0):

I just customized useSelector hook to avoid that and it works nice

```js
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { _lodash } from '../../../lodash'

export const useCloneSelector = (selector = (obj) => obj) => {
  const selectWithClonedState = (state = {}, ...others) => selector(_lodash.cloneDeep(state), ...others)
  return useSelector(selectWithClonedState, _lodash.isEqual)
}

export { useDispatch, useSelector }
```